# Instrumenting a Java anonymous inner class object

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation

So, given the following code:

```
public MyInterface getMyInterface() {
    return new MyInterface() {
        public SomethingElse getSomethingElse() {
           // ....
        }
    }
}

...
MyInterface obj = getMyInterface();
```

Is there some way to instrument a call to getSomethingElse() on that `obj`? To go in and do some bytecode modification or something?

I have production code in there that in a different situation (call it "design time") I want to add some tracing/logging and such code for help in troubleshooting and analysis. Performance is critical for the production case so I want to leave it without the extra tracing/logging overhead. But in the design time situation, I want to have all the trace info.

Comment: here are instances when you should use inner classes: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-03/02-qa-innerclass.html. As for logging, I strongly suggest you log (just make it on another thread so your app is not IO bound); it helps tremendously w debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what you're asking, although there are definitely better ways to accomplish it - the most obvious would be to create a default implementation of MyInterface, and then a "tracing" subclass of it that extends and logs before invoking the superclass version.

If instrumentation is your only option, then when running at design time, you can start your project with a java agent in Java 5 or add a java agent to the classpath at runtime in Java 6.  See the [instrumentation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

To instrument the class, you will probably want to use a tool like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).   The steps would be something like this:

1. In your Agent class, implement java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer .
2. In your agentmain() or premain() method, [request](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#addTransformer%28java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer%29) to transform classes.
3. When you receive a call to the [transform](http://goo.gl/PYzma) method, you can check if the class implements MyInterface by using Class.getInterfaces().
4. Optionally, you can check to see if its Class.getEnclosingClass() is the class in which you wrote/found this code.
5. If the Class passes these sanity checks, then create a ClassWriter that adds logging to the getSomethingElse() method.  The [ASMifier](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/index.html) helps a lot when trying to figure out how to generate the code you want.

Then, in production, none of that code will exist.  In development, you would add your Java Agent in your environment, which would enable your debugging.

Again, there are almost certainly better ways to do this, but there are good reasons to use instrumentation, and this is a mini-crash course in doing it.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn on logging on in development, the simplest thing to do is

```
if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
   LOGGER.debug("my debug message");
```

The over head added is sub-nanosecond so even if you are working on a system where every nano-seconds count, this is still the best pattern to use.

---

You can get the class with

```
 Class.forName("package.OuterClass$NNN");
```

You need to call a constructor which takes an instance of the outer class.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question which was about how to instrument/modify bytecode.

Comment: True, I thought you wanted to know how to create it.

Comment: Answered the question asked indirectly. Checking a debug switch will be a small fraction of the time it takes to create an object.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a good case for using [aspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

You can simply apply logging/tracing code around any methods you want in your testing environment and leave them out when you move to production.